# Cost monitoring of AWS EMR spark logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr-serverless

I'm trying to monitor the cost of storing logs generated by my emr serverless spark applications. Is there a way to add AWS cost monitoring to the spark logs of an application ran in EMR serverless? I know cost monitoring is done by adding tags to objects, is it possible to add tags to the log output of spark applications? Or is there another approach that can achieve this?